# Can i use cross sectional absolute deviation to detect whether or not there is herding behavior in one specific year IPO

Tags: regression, statistical-finance, event-study

If I want to measure herding behavior of one specific year IPO, can I only use the initial return of every IPO stocks in that specific year for the CSAD regression?

Comment: It sounds like an interesting question, but could you please add some more details?

Comment: @DimitriVulis thank you for the reply, sorry if my wording is not good, because english is not my first language . So I want to do a research on whether or not there is a herding behavior on a specific year IPO using CSAD, so I will only use the initial return of every stock for the Ri,t and as for the Rm,t I will use the market return of the day the company is doing the IPO and for the N is the amount of company going IPO that year, am I allowed to do that ? Or there is a certain rule that must be followed when I want to use CSAD, thank you Dimitri

Comment: Please include the additional information provided in your comment by editing the question, thank you.